# Can we have Dark Mode?

Tags: feature-request, status-declined

A dark mode theme for substrate.stackexchange.com would be heyely appreciated!

I know stackoverflow.com supports this and it has been a feature requested on stackexchange for some time.

Thank you!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As an alternative to native dark mode, I use the plugin [Dark Reader](https://darkreader.org/) in my browsers, and it provides a reasonable dark theme.

[image]

But yes, I would love a native dark mode if that is an option.

Comment: if it gets rebranded to polkadot.stackexchange.com, is it possible to also apply the standard polkadot colour theme from here along with the dark theme https://github.com/polkadot-js/apps/blob/master/packages/apps-config/src/ui/colors.ts#L116

Answer (score 4):

At the moment, it is questionable whether Dark Mode will be rolled out to the rest of the network at all. From the [announcement post](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/395949/dark-mode-beta-help-us-root-out-low-contrast-and-un-converted-bits):

> #### Future releases
>
> At this point, the focus of Dark Mode is on Stack Overflow and we’ll eventually bring it to MSO. While the retheming we did across the network two years ago makes updating our [styles] easier, creating dark versions of all of our sites, particularly the custom-designed ones, is going to be a huge challenge we’re not able to contemplate at this time. The artwork on some of those sites simply can’t be made dark because we don’t have access to the original art files and, to be honest, some of the themes will always be better as-is.

Now, sites without a custom design like Substrate.SE will probably be easier to convert to Dark Mode (I've even seen one of the Community Managers, Catija, mentioning this, but I can't find it) but I wouldn't get my hopes up.

Comment: This answer covers what staff would've responded with.

Comment: any progress towards dark mode outside https://stackoverflow.com/users/preferences ?

Comment: @Nuke just [this post by Catija](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/378976/295232) from May last year.